# What's the meaning of "sampling the light source" in multiple importance sampling?

Tags: graphics, rendering, raytracing

I totally understand why the magenta light source is not well sampled in the "Sampling the BRDF". But I don't understand why such a big blue light source is not well sampled in the "Sampling the light source".

What does "Sampling the light source" mean? In my view, it bounces a ray from the intersected surface to the light source directly. If so, the blue shouldn't be so sparse in the "Sampling the light source" picture.

[image: Picture here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my view, it bounces a ray from the intersected surface to the light
>   source directly.

To quote from chapter 9 of [Veach's thesis](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/),

> The light source sampling strategy does not consider the BSDF of the glossy surface. Thus when the BSDF has a large influence on the overall shape of the integrand (e.g. when it is a narrow, peaked function), then sampling the light source leads to high variance.

In other words, when you sample the light source instead of the BSDF/BRDF, you're picking a point on the surface of the light and figuring out how much light that point is bringing back to your intersection point. Since you could be picking a point anywhere on the light, it's not necessarily the case that the ray from the light to your intersection point is going to hit your original intersection point at exactly the correct angle it would need to bounce back to the camera. In fact, it's less likely the shinier your surface is, and the larger your light source is.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble understanding this too. Thanks Daniel for explanation.
[light sampling noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCd6.png)

So if I understand the noise in Light Sampling correctly: point A' is reflection of A. But since we sample whole blue lamp area, then some of the sample rays (pink ones) will give zero radiance, since they are not laying on on the half reflection-view vector)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please avoid "thanks"/"I'm having this problem too" statements in your answer. It's flagged as low-quality. The format of the site is Q&A, not a discussion forum.